# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte ERROR when querying data

Tags: postgresql

I have created this foreign SQL Server using [tds_fdw](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw) foreign data wrapper:

```
CREATE SERVER servprod_sqlprod_mydb
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER tds_fdw 
OPTIONS (servername 'XX.XX.XX.XX', port '1501',msg_handler 'notice', database 'WHATEVER');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
    SERVER servprod_sqlprod_mydb
    OPTIONS (username 'xxx', password 'xxxxxxxxxx');



CREATE FOREIGN TABLE tds_test (
    caclamun character varying,
    caclacal character varying,
    catipvia character varying,
    cadescri character varying,
    caidenti character varying,
    cafechal character varying,
    cafechba character varying)
    SERVER servprod_sqlprod_mydb
    OPTIONS (table_name 'dbo.MYSQL TABLE');
```

When opening the table I am getting:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
```

I think it is a postgresql issue and not tds_fdw's, but I am not sure.

Comment: the error message suggests that the source is not returning UTF-8 data, maybe delete rows from the table (or use a copy of the table) until the problem goes away.

Comment: @Jasen I tried with different tables and it works...I don't know how to bypass this issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem adding character_set 'UTF-8' when creating foreign server. 
Example:

```
CREATE SERVER myserver 
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER tds_fdw 
OPTIONS (servername 'localhost', port '1501',msg_handler 'notice', database 'mydb', character_set 'UTF-8');
```